# is there anyway to force a dependency to use the latest version of one of its dependency

Tags: rust

In my project I depend on package A

Package A depends on package B

Package A says

```
    [dependencies]
    B = "1.0"
```

Now there is a v 2 of B. Most of my dependencies now say they want 2. But A still points at 1.  So I end up with 2 versions of B

I am surprised that there seems to be no way to say 'I want to use 1.0 or greater and I mean that 2.0 is fine as well as 1.1'

Anyway is there some way I can force this

EDIT: the answer is no. And the rust versioning system specifically avoids it, and there is no way for a lib author to say that they are happy with any version greater than a certain one.

Comment: *"I am surprised that there seems to be no way to say 'I want to use 1.0 or greater and I mean that 2.0 is fine as well as 1.1'"* - There already is, cargo automatically uses the newest version that is compatible with all dependencies. The problem here is that `2.0` is not [semver compatible](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#semver-compatibility) with `1.0`, so it cannot upgrade to it. Most likely package A will have to make internal changes to be compatible with B `2.0`.

Comment: @Finomnis - so there is no way to say - 'i am happy with any newer version'. My expectation is that v2 is a non breaking upgrade of v1, but it seems that its not possible to say this (as the package A author)

Comment: That's the whole point of semver - a change from `1.0.0` to `2.0.0` indicates that it **is** in fact a breaking upgrade.

Comment: *"as the package A author"* - that is a small detail you completely missed to mention in your question. If you are the author of the A package, then it's of course different. The A package can of course specify that it is compatible with multiple major versions, [like described here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html). (For example `= "*"`, `= ">=1.0"`)

Comment: *"there is no way for a lib author to say that they are happy with any version greater than a certain one."* - this one is incorrect, as the *lib user* you can't say that, as the *lib author* you can say whatever you want.

Comment: @Finomnis - I still think rust has a big problem here. Concrete example, syn is used a lot. The project I am contributing to uses multiple libs that depend on it. A package moved to syn v2, now I have to have duplicate syn packages (the chekcin CI actualy runs 'cargo check deny bans' to disallow multiple versions). I then have to go round and beg the libs that point at v1 to upgrade to v2, others have done the same (I found 2 3 month old PRs for one). Really there should be a way for a lib to say I will take any version > than x

Comment: This is not a Rust problem. You sacrifice stability with this. If a library upgrades from 1.1 to 1.2, Rust (cargo actually) allows everyone to update, exactly like you wish. Only for major upgrades (like 1.5 to 2.0) it doesn't. And this is a good thing - a major change is explicitly only for changes that could break projects that use it. So why would you say "simply use any version, I don't care if updating breaks everything?" This would mitigate the entire reason we use semver in the first place.

Comment: A library could be completely rewritten and every single function call could be different from version 1.5 to 2.0. This isn't a hypothetical thing; it happened, and this is exactly what major version changes are for. Why would you want everyone to upgrade to it automatically, breaking everything?

Comment: @Finomnis - but its rare to break on upgrade. I should , as the consumer, be able to say that I want any version > x including x+1,x+2... if i break then I will investigate. There are all sorts of version string formats but not one to say that

Comment: No, it's not rare. Its expected. Thats **exactly** what a major version change is communicating. Semver exists to improve build reliability, allowing automatic updates beyond major versions will void the entire reason why we use semver in the first place. A library that updates a dependency major version basically communicates "if you want to update to my newer version, you need to update the dependency as well, otherwise stuff might break". Note that updating a dependency major version requires a library major version update as well.

Comment: In the case of `syn` it's not a problem, having multiple `syn` versions on your system really doesn't bother. Why do you think this would be bad? `syn` doesn't end up in your executable, it's a library for the build system only.